# GameObject[] does not contain a definition for Concat (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Estoy intentando concatenar dos arrays en C#, pero tengo errores porque estoy intentando guardar GameObjects en ellos. Me dice que eso se guardaría en una variable de tipo GameObject[]. Pero cuando la cambio a GameObject[], me da el error de que no tiene una definición para Concat.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] orangeBolinches;
    private GameObject[] blueBolinches;
    private GameObject[] bolinches;

    void Update()
    {
        orangeBolinches = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("orange");  
        blueBolinches = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("blue");

        bolinches = orangeBolinches.Concat(blueBolinches);
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal que te de ese error, los [array de C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0) no disponen de ningún método `Concat`. Si quieres un array con todos los elementos de ambos arrays debes concatenar a mano:

```
bolinches = new GameObject[orangeBolinches.Length + blueBolinches.Length];
orangeBolinches.CopyTo(bolinches, 0);
blueBolinches.CopyTo(bolinches, orangeBolinches.Length);
```